Spivak Chapter 7, Problem 19b: Continuity
Here is the question from Spivak. Suppose 0<a<1 but $a \neq 1/n$ for any natural number n. Find a function f that (1) is continuous on [0,1], (2) is such that f(0)=f(1), and (3) is such that $f(x) \neq f(x+a)$ for all x.
Here's the beginning of the answer from a previous thread (link to thread below). We know that $1/n+1 <a < 1/n$. It follows that $1-na \in [0,a]$.  Let $f(ka + x) = kf(a) + f(x)$. A consequence of this, according to the answer in the thread below, is that $f(ka) = kf(a)$. I don't understand why this must be the case: why don't we have that $f(ka) = f(ka +0) = kf(a) + f(0)$.
Spivak' Calculus Chapter 7 Problem 19(b) [continuity]

Actually, what we have is $1/(n+1)<a<1/n$, instead of $1/n+1<a<1/n$.
